# How do I get the whole offset of a compose component

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I know how to get the X,Y coordinates of a button/or component, but I want to know every corner offset or at least the **right bottom offset**.
For example I'm getting the left top coordiantes from:

```
Modifier.onGloballyPositioned{
    it.positionInRoot().x
    it.positionInRoot().y
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to know bottom right coordinates so I can calculate the difference offset inside the component?

Edit: **Possible solution ->** use spacer next to the component:
Let's imagine that we want to get the right bottom of a button.

```
Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                            it.positionInRoot().x
                            it.positionInRoot().y
                         }
         ) {...}
         Row(modifier =Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom) {
              Spacer(
                  Modifier
                   .height(0.dp)
                   .width(0.dp)
                   .onGloballyPositioned {
                       it.positionInRoot().x
                       it.positionInRoot().y
                   }
              )
          }
    }
```

Comment: What is the final goal?

Comment: Write my canvas in the same position as the button, for that I need to know its position and do the math to center it @GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for `LayoutCoordinates.boundsInRoot()`

```
Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
    val rect = layoutCoordinates.boundsInRoot()
    println("${rect.topLeft} ${rect.bottomRight}")
}
```

---

Most of time you don't need that for layout in Compose

You can place both canvas and your view in a `Box`, add `matchParentSize` modifier to your canvas and it'll be same size as your view. Inside `Canvas` you can use parameters like `size`, `center`, etc values to draw

```
Box {
    Canvas(Modifier.matchParentSize()) {
        // here you can access size, center, etc
        drawRect(Color.Green)
    }
    Text("hello")
}
```

Comment: @Barrufet I've updated my answer, because most probably you actually don't need to use `onGloballyPositioned`

Comment: Damn I'm new to canvas and I didn't know about this, thank you for updating it, definitely helps a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this with `drawWithContent()`.

```kotlin
Modifier.drawWithContent {
    //Here you can access 'size', offset starts from (0f,0f)
    print("Bottom Right ${this.size.height} , ${this.size.width}")
}
```